# How to make API request to Vimeo videos in iOS application?

Tags: ios, objective-c, vimeo-api, vimeo-ios

I'm developing an iOS app(coded in Objective-c) which plays Vimeo videos. Its an In App Purchase application. I already have websites where users can buy videos. I have Vimeo PRO account. I don't know how to get direct link to those videos using Vimeo API.

Is requesting for videos part mine or it is done in back-end(in my case PHP)? So how to make API request to those videos I own in order to show them in my app? Thanks

Comment: Please post your code. What are you currently trying that does not yield playback URLs?

Comment: Playback URLs should be available in the JSON response for a video.

Answer (score 0):

Did you take a look at following url:

https://github.com/vimeo/VIMNetworking

If you still facing problem then I hope, it will give answer of all your problems.

Let me know if you have any other problem. I will try to solve it.

Comment: We did it. We did this part at back end because user must need to go to VIMEO login page to get permission from Vimeo and access token, which was not feasible for us. So not using VIMNetworking anymore.  Is there anyway to avoid this? Thanks for your concern.

Comment: Yes, You can use Vimeo account personal access token and make Vimeo api call from iOS application. Personal access token will work for single user application. If you have not requirement as every user must login via his/her separate Vimeo account.